# Encrypt a chain and send it to a php server in android

Tags: java, php, android, encoding

I need to send a chain encoded (with Java) thought http post and decode it once received in the php server. How can I do it?

The security level required is low-mid

Answer (score 2):

For low security I would say make sure your java client and php code have the same passphrase and just use DES excryption.
[An example of encrypting using DES in Java](http://exampledepot.com/egs/javax.crypto/DesString.html), 
[Php Example](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/129177)
The excryption type you use doesn't matter as long as both your java client and php server have the same passphrase.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one example of Java/php encryption:

http://schneimi.wordpress.com/2008/11/25/aes-128bit-encryption-between-java-and-php/